# Creating and Passing HTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

I am using a javascript tooltip constructor that allows HTML as part of its content. I want write a helper function that returns an object representing the HTML (as the exact HTML will depend on the constructor input parameter). How can I do this? (The pseudo code is something like this:

```
function makeHTML(data1, data2){
   var HTML = ""
   if (property holds){
      add the following to the HTML:
           "<br>" +
           "<b>" + "Constant " + "</b>" +  "<br>" +
           "<b>" + varibale + "! " + "</b>" + moredata1 +
           "<br>"
   }
   if (another property holds){
      add the following to the HTML:
           "<br>" +
           "<b>" + "Constant2 " + "</b>" +  "<br>" +
           "<b>" + varibale2 + "! " + "</b>" + moredata2 +
           "<br>"
   }
```

). I am running into problems trying to return the tags and quotes in general.

When I am filling the content of the tooltip without dynamically created HTML, the proper formatting has tags in quotes (e.g "
"):

```
return {
      title: information
      content:
        "<br>" + 
        data[9] + variable + "<br>"
```

}
Now, I want to make it so that before the return, I can call makeHTML and write:

```
var dynamicHTML = makeHTML(data1, data2)
return {
  title: information
  content: dynamicHTML
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just store the html in either a data- attribute or in a sibling node of your HTML (that is hidden). That way the tooltip and the thing needing the tooltip are together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an Object that accepts data before outputing ex:

```
function dynamicElement(){
    var self = this, html = "";

    self.setProp = function(props){
        for(prop in props){
            html += "<p>"+prop+"</p>";
        }
    }

    self.draw(where){
        where.innerHtml = html;
    }

    return self;
}

//Usage
var x = new dynamicElement();

x.setProp([1,2,3]);
x.draw(document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.write("your html here")`.

However, if this is something you find you're doing often, you mgiht want to use server-side scripting with [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php), or use some JavaScript libraries/frameworks like [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) or [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/).

Comment: Bad idea. This will overwrite the DOM completely.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you don't use `element.innerHTML = myHTMLValue;` ?
Let's see more information here :[HTML DOM innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: "content" refers to the content of the tooltip. I am writing this in Javascript and pulling information from an API. My goal is to be able to write the HTML using conditions logic and pass this HTML into the content field of the tooltip constructor.

Comment: If you create your logic and create a HTML content, you can give it to your HTML file and display it. Imagine the first kind of object have `a` condition, you create for example `element.getElementById('test').innerHTML = <p>First One</p>` and the second one have `b` condition, you can do the same thing with anothers tags.

Comment: @user7518095 I create you an example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axg4trrp/)